# Selenium wire attribute error when launching chromedriver with a remote debugging port

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumwire

This one has really stumped me.

I need to be able to launch my chromedriver with a remote debugging port. This works fine in regular selenium but when done with selenium-wire, I get the following error.

AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'pop'

Full code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver 
from seleniumwire.utils import decode
import json
import time

PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/Users/benfield/Documents/Chrome debug test')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=chrome_options,seleniumwire_options=chrome_options)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/benfield/Desktop/betbot/testwire.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=chrome_options,seleniumwire_options=chrome_options)
  File "/Users/benfield/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/seleniumwire/webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    config = self._setup_backend(seleniumwire_options)
  File "/Users/benfield/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/seleniumwire/webdriver.py", line 42, in _setup_backend
    addr=seleniumwire_options.pop('addr', '127.0.0.1'),
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Problem solved: driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=chrome_options)